# Can i convert a date input from html textbox into 2 variables for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I should enter the date as MM YYYY in the input field then a given formula should be applied to the input, the HTML code is

`<p> End of Investment: <input type="text" title="Date as MM YYYY" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012]) [0-9]{4}" id="Invest"> </p>`
[Input box picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWcaF.png)

How can I split the value given into 2 variables to apply them in the javascript formula?
Should be as

> 12 * (2020-YYYY) + (12-MM)

Comment: Please provide an example of an input and output of what you want done.

Comment: End of Investment: entered as mm yyyy.
The final value is calculated on the basis
of a fixed monthly interest rate of 1%.
• The amount displayed is rounded.
• The investment is calculated from the current date (current
month) to the entered end date. In this example, the number
of months to consider is
12 * (2020-yyyy) + (12-mm)